# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for ''django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm''

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I'm using Django 1.5.12 and I get this error and don't know how to solve it. Other 'NoReverseMatch' post didn't help me

> NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'uidb36': u'mg', u'token': u'4mb-cc37d48'}' not found.

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
(r'^my-account/password-reset/$', 
  'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset', {
    'post_reset_redirect': '/my-account/password-reset/done/',
    'template_name': 'password_reset/password_reset_form.html',
    'email_template_name': 'password_reset/password_reset_email.html'
  }),
(r'^my-account/password-reset/done/$', 
  'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done', {
    'template_name': 'password_reset/password_reset_done.html'
  }),
(r'^my-account/password-reset/((?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+))/$', 
  'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', {
    'post_reset_redirect': '/my-account/password-reset/complete/',
    'template_name': 'password_reset/password_reset_confirm.html'
  })
```

**password_reset_email.html**

```
{% autoescape off %}
You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset for your 
user account.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 
'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm' uidb36=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem ?

Comment: my bad i wrote the error myself but it's u'uidb36 in my console. I edit the post

Comment: Django 1.5.X has been out of unsupported for years and is insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the outer parentheses around `(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)`:

```
(r'^my-account/password-reset/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', 
 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', {
     'post_reset_redirect': '/my-account/password-reset/complete/',
     'template_name': 'password_reset/password_reset_confirm.html'
})
```

Comment: Ok it's seems to work. I'm ashamed I've lost so much time on this stupid error. Thank you.